# Kubernetes ingress nginx not matching sub paths

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to make a simple example of ingress-nginx on google cloud, but it's not matching the subpaths:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /one
          backend:
            serviceName: test-one-backend
            servicePort: 80
        - path: /two
          backend:
            serviceName: test-two-backend
            servicePort: 80
```

When I call, http://server/one works, but when I call  http://server/one/path I get a 404.
I'd tried several things like using regex, but is simply not working

The backends are just, echo servers that reply always on any path.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a `/*` at the end of the path:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /one/*
          backend:
            serviceName: test-one-backend
            servicePort: 80
        - path: /two
          backend:
            serviceName: test-two-backend
            servicePort: 80
```

It's not really [documented widely as of today](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1120), but in essence the `path` translates to a [`location {}`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) block in the nginx.conf

Answer (score 4):

Attention it changed in version 0.22.0 of ingress-nginx. checkout example at https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/examples/rewrite/README.md
Now you have to work with captured groups to pass a subpath to the rewrite-target.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something(/|$)(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

This definition matches the exact string for the path. If you want to include subdirectories you can use the wildcard `*`. Your modified definition should look like this:

```
- path: /one/*
  backend:
    serviceName: test-one-backend
    servicePort: 80
```

I am not sure if `http://server/one` (without the slash at the end) still works. In that case you have to keep your old definition and add another one like the above.